# How can I uninstall Qt5 that I installed from .run?

Tags: uninstall, qt5

I installed Qt from `qt-linux-opensource-5.0.1-x86_64-offline.run` file.

It works fine, but I am unable to use KDE libs in it. So can anyone please say how to uninstall it??
I could also not find any like uninstall or something in the installed directory.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

I finally managed to do it,

to uninstall, I managed go to the installation directory, there is an executable called MaintenanceTool, we need to run it, in order to uninstall and remove Qt.

what to do:

open terminal,

1. go to the installed directory `cd /opt/Qt`
2. run MaintenanceTools by the following command `./MaintenanceTool`

and it is done.....

Comment: You are a hero and a scholar.

Comment: The default directory where `MaintenanceTool` is on `/opt/Qt`

Comment: After running ./MaintenanceTool, the GUI installer will ask for your username and password. Look at the bottom for the 'Uninstall only' checkbox. Selecting that box disables the username and password, and enables the 'next' so you can uninstall.

Comment: For me it was in the home directory (i.e.  `~/Qt`) but +1

Answer (score 0):

Arch 2021

Remove binaries:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/assistant
sudo rm /usr/bin/assistant-qt5
sudo rm /usr/bin/designer
sudo rm /usr/bin/designer-qt5
sudo rm /usr/bin/linguist
sudo rm /usr/bin/linguist-qt5 
sudo rm /usr/bin/qdbusviewer
sudo rm /usr/bin/qdbusviewer-qt5
```

Remove application shortcuts:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/assistant.desktop 
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/designer.desktop 
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/linguist.desktop 
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/qdbusviewer.desktop
```