# How to uninstall all Qt from ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, uninstall, qt

My application using `Qt` lib stop working, after trying all suggestion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944835/genymotion-stop-working-on-ubuntu-16-04) I came up with uninstalling all `Qt` lib so that install them again from scratch.
when I run `$qtchooser -list-versions` it list following for me:

```
4
5
default
qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt4
qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt5
```

I try `sudo apt autoremove '.*qt5.*-dev'` and `sudo apt autoremove '.*qt4.*-dev'` which stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625379/how-to-uninstall-qt5/39625523#39625523) how can I uninstall them cleanly? Is any important app using them?

Comment: Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/257822/how-can-i-uninstall-qt5-that-i-installed-from-run. This might help you..